# Why isn't my Rails Custom Validator working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I'm creating a store that allow users to purchase greeting cards (Happy Birthday, Valentine's Day)

I have two models: `Card` and `Recipient`

```
class Card < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :recipient

  def valid_name
    if @recipient && @recipient.name.nil?
      @card.errors.full_messages.push("Name can't be blank")
    end
  end

  validate :valid_name
  validates_associated :recipient
  validates :recipient, presence: true
  validates :note, length: { in: 1..200 }

class Recipient < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_one :card

  validates :name, presence: true

end
```

**Card Controller**

```
def new
  @card = Card.new
  @card.build_recipient                                   
end

def create
  @card = Card.new(card_params)
  if @card.save
    flash[:notice] = "Your card was successfully added to your cart!"
    redirect_to :back
  else
    flash[:danger] = "Something was wrong"
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

**Paramaters**

```
def card_params
  params.require(:card).permit(:note, :amount, :recipient_attributes:[:name, :email])
end
```

I don't have a `RecipientsController` but I don't think I need one.

I would like to validate the fields in my `Recipients` model in a form for purchasing a Card.

I've tried `validates_associated` and adding my own validators. I just need to validate my recipient (customers) info.

Comment: Because you never save `@card`, check your create action try find problem.

Comment: There are lots of things wrong with this code: 1) It looks like your using nested attributes but nested attributes don't work for `belongs_to` relationships. 2) There is no `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in your example 3) `if card.save` instead of `@card.save`

Comment: 4) i found another invalid syntax in `card_params` `:recipient_attributes:[:name, :email]`